# Identify an user IP behind a Proxy with Express.js

Tags: node.js, http, security, express

I've a site that sometimes receives many, unusual requests and want to block the requester. The session id is different for all requests but x-forwarded-for header is always the same.

Now, the x-forwarded-for IP I traced it with a geo-locator and it shows it is from a known ISP (Cox), so I can't just block all incoming requests from that ISP. The remoteAddress shows the address of MY load balancer.

Any idea what I can do to block this person without blocking all the ISP customers?

Comment: Can you add to your question all the headers you get on the request?

Comment: Blocking one IP from an ISP doesn't necessarily mean blocking all requests from that ISP. Actually, in the general case, it won't. Even if the ISP had all traffic running through proxies or NATs, in the case of an ISP of this size, you would see many different IPs in a pool rather than a single IP.